# Efficiently replace strings in 20k potential matches

Tags: r, performance, gsub

I want to replace substrings of a string and want to check against 20k+ candidates.

Is there a more efficient way than to split the 20k into subgroups of 900 candidates and Loop over them? Can i do this search in <0.3s?

**What i tried:**

1) Paste 20k candidates in a string. This results in an error, see below. (Probably too Long of a string for 64bit?)

2) Create subgroups of 900 candidates and Loop over the subgroups. (That takes longer than a second).

**Reproducible Code:**

```
n <- 20000 # have to go down to 900 here. 
words <- sapply(sample(4:10, size = n, replace = T), FUN = function(nr){
  paste(sample(letters, nr, replace = T), collapse = "")
})


sentence <- "This is my sentence where i want to replace matches"
replacement <- "REPLACEMENT"

library(microbenchmark)
pattern <- paste(words, collapse = "|") # probably too long for a string
clean <- gsub(pattern = pattern, replacement = replacement, x = sentence) # fails
```

Comment: Are the `words` static or dynamic? If you have a specified list, it can be shrunk to a greater extent.

Comment: Do you only want to replace whole words or also parts of words? If the former, I would not use regex but split the sentence into words and match them against your `words`.

Comment: thanks for your questions. My attempt to make the question reproducible made it unclear, you are right. The words are static. Replace Whole words would work yes. Thanks for the word matching idea!

Comment: The splitting-with-space approach is only good if all words in the input are space separated. Once there is some punctuation next to the word, it won't work. Or, if there are tabs, line breaks, it won't work either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That only means you might need a regex for splitting ...

Comment: @Roland But you also use `paste(splitsentence, collapse = " ")`, and then it will be hard to keep the same whitespace (whitespace amount).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a regex to match any word chars (`\w+`) and a callback as the replacement argument for `stringr::str_replace_all`:

```
str_replace_all(sentence, "\\w+", function(w) ifelse(w %in% words, replacement, w))
```

Test:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(splitmatch = { str_replace_all(sentence, "\\w+", function(w) ifelse(w %in% words, replacement, w)) })
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 splitmatch 1.217353 1.26916 1.545855 1.395634 1.678778 4.982447   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the sentence into words:

```
n <- 20000 # have to go down to 900 here. 
words <- sapply(sample(4:10, size = n, replace = T), FUN = function(nr){
  paste(sample(letters, nr, replace = T), collapse = "")
})

words[1e4] <- "i" #to have a match

sentence <- "This is my sentence where i want to replace matches"
replacement <- "REPLACEMENT"

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(splitmatch =
  {
    splitsentence <- strsplit(sentence, " ")[[1]]

    matches <- vapply(splitsentence, function(x) x %in% words, FUN.VALUE = TRUE)

    splitsentence[matches] <- replacement

    paste(splitsentence, collapse = " ")
    #[1] "This is my sentence where REPLACEMENT want to replace matches"
  })
#Unit: microseconds
#      expr   min     lq     mean median      uq    max neval
#splitmatch 957.4 986.95 1222.963 995.15 1005.85 7534.6   100
```